# GitHub Commit Comment Notification for Microsoft Teams

Tags: github, microsoft-teams, commit

I'm using Microsoft Teams and GitHub and wanted to know if there is a way to show all new commit comments in a channel.
Or even if this doesn't exists if it's possible to add GitHub Runner, Webhook or Action to call something if someone adds a comment to a commit.

Best regards
PD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could achieve this via this [workflow](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/microsoft-teams-notification)

You can [configure the workflow trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows) as per your requirement as well.